# You must use node.js and npm javascript to use libraries as react.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm learning react.js but in every example I see using node.js with npm, node.js and npm are really necessary to use javascript libraries as react.js?

I need a simple explanation please.

Excuse my English, I am a Spanish speaker.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't need **node.js** and **npm** to use `react.js`.
You can start using **'react.js'** just by including `react` and `react-dom` in your html file's `<head>`

e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React!</title>
    <script src="local_path/react.js"></script>
    <script src="local_path/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here Babel is needed to perform the JSX transformation in the browser.

Comment: Using node.js and npm can help you organize your packages and automate certain tasks during development, as well as bundle your javascript, CSS, etc. for testing/production (with the relevant packages of course).

Comment: Fizz is more successful, I am creating a bundle with webpack but my problem is that I had doubts if necessary lift a node.js server or only have to send the bundle?